# Extract Email from Bulk Text - Error

Tags: python, html, extract, bulk

I would like to extract all the email addresses included in an HTML code. I wrote this very simple code (I'm a super basic python writer, I'm just trying to learn):

```
#coding=utf-8
import urllib
import re

html = urllib.urlopen('http://giacomobonvini.com').read()

r = re.compile(r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)')
results = r.findall(html)

emails = ""
for x in results:
   emails += str(x) + "\n"

print emails
```

The problem is that, even if the code works, the email are printed in this way:

"giacomo.bonvini@gmail.com < / span"

"giacomo.bonvini@gmail.com < br"

I would line not to have "< / span" and " < br".

Do you have any idea?
Thanks
Giacomo

Comment: Can you rephrase the question?  There is no ``"`` in ``giacomo.bonvini@gmail.com``...

Comment: @ArminRigo I'm sorry I don't know why the text editor didn't consider all the digits I put. I split them in order to let you see what's written initially.

Answer (score 0):

```
r'(\b[\w.]+@+[\w.]+.+[\w.]\b)'
```

The problem is likely the `.+` combination, which matches anything.  Maybe you meant to match a single dot instead?  If so, use for example `[.]`